# Upload video to Facebook with Javascript, trough the the Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, file-upload

Is it possible to upload a video from my server, to a users profile , trough the Graph API, using only Javascript

Example

```
FB.api('/user_id/videos', 'post', {message: 'Facebook Video Upload', access_token:token, source:video, type:'video'}, function(response)(){})
```

In the permission settings I have 'video_upload' and when try this example I get a 'Error occured(#353) Missing video file ', but when I test the source('video/test.mp4') of the video in the browser, it shows it